# Google map tiles not rendered properly while dragging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have using google map api in angularjs.

If i do dragging, most of times tiles are not loading fully. It showing grey background.

I have refereed some answers in google. They have suggested resize features.

I have tried the following code

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

It is  not solving my issue.  and i have tried one more event called `tilesloaded`

but this is also not working.

```
tilesloaded: function (map) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    console.log("tilesloaded")
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                });
            }
```

How to solve this issue?

Dont make this is a duplicate question. I have tried all the answers. Here i need different solutions.

Comment: You mentioned it happens intermittently. Could it be an internet connection issue? e.g. slow connection? Have you tried running it else where? preferably with a ok connection.

Comment: I could able to reproduce all the time. I have checked connection speed also